# decl_storage macro syntax

Tags: syntax, trait

```
decl_storage! {
    trait Store for Module<T: Trait> as KittyStorage {
        Kitties get(kitty): map T::Hash => Kitty<T::Hash, T::Balance>;
```

1. What is this `for` use?
2. What is `Store` ? is this a trait?
3. then `Module` is what?
4. `decl_storage!` macro is for what purpose? create multiple storage object suites?
5. what is `<T: Trait> as KittyStorage` ?
   you give name Module as `KittyStorage`?
6. 

```
Kitties get(kitty): map T::Hash => Kitty<T::Hash, T::Balance>;
```

`Kitties` object has `get` method, attribute is `kitty`, then map `iterate T::Hash` ,
return `Kitty` object which has `T::Hash` and `T::Balance` trait.

is it right?

Answer (score 1):

Well , I really don't think there is a need for you to keep hustling FRAME V1 syntax. Because The declarative macros used there don't follow rust syntax.
So I think you should focus on V2. And It will be hard for you to get further help in your journey if you keep using V1 as now V2 is used officially and it is easy to debug

Comment: Thank you Mrisho

Answer (score 1):

The `decl_*!` macros were deprecated specifically for the confusion they cause, and as illustrated in this question.

Because they define their own syntax, which is not Rust, you basically need to understand how the macro parses the code block to understand what is going on.

I do not suggest you keep moving forward with FRAME V1, and instead suggest you use the [FRAME V2](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/discussions/7788) macros.

Anyway, to answer your question:

1. `trait Store for Module` is trying to look like the `impl Trait for Struct` syntax, and it is doing the same thing. There is a trait `Store` which is being implemented for `Module`.
2. Yes it is a trait which is generated on the fly for each pallet. It lists the storage items available in the pallet.
3. `Module` is a struct which represents the whole pallet. In all the latest pallets, this is renamed to `Pallet`.
4. `decl_storage!` is used to define storage items which can be used in your runtime logic, and store data on the blockchain. It provides access between your pallet code, and the Substrate database.
5. `<T: Trait>` is part of `Module<T: Trait>`, and it is a [generic parameter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-01-syntax.html). `KittyStorage` is the [storage prefix](https://www.shawntabrizi.com/substrate/querying-substrate-storage-via-rpc/) name used when generating storage for the pallet.
6. is not a question.

Comment: Thank you Shawn. your tutorial is awesome